# Show that entropy $(p1,...,pi,...,pj,...,pm)$, < entropy $(p1,..., (pi+pj)/2 ,..., (pi+pj)/2 ,...,pm)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory

Show that the entropy of the probability distribution, $(p1,...,pi,...,pj,...,pm)$, is less
than the entropy of the distribution $(p1,..., (pi+pj)/2 ,..., (pi+pj)/2 ,...,pm)$.

I don't understand what is meant by this? I don't see the pattern..

Let's say I have $(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$ for the first one, is the second one $(p_1,(p_1+p_3)/2,(p_2+p_4)/2,p_4)$? Always take average of previous and next term?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the second probability distribution keeps all but two components invariant and sets those two components both equal to the average of them. And what is required to show is
$$-p\ln p-q \ln q\leq-(p+q)\ln\frac2{p+q}$$
Or equivalently, by Jensen inequality
$$S(\pi)=-\sum_i^n\pi_i\ln\pi_i$$
is concave down, which is directly followed by the definition.

Comment: thank you! will attempt it now